# Java and endianness

Tags: java, cross-platform, endianness

How does java take care of endianness?  In case if you are moving your application from a little endian to a big endian or vice versa.
How are the data members or properties of class affected?

Comment: Endianness only matters if you're reading/writing raw data over e.g. a network interface or disk.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, or receiving data via IPC or via a pipe or from a file or ... really anytime you're reading or writing data and the thing on the other end isn't java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are mapping a buffer of a larger type over a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) then you can specify the endianness using the `ByteOrder` values.  Older core libraries assume network order.

From `ByteBuffer`:

> Access to binary data
>
> This class defines methods for reading and writing values of all other primitive types, except boolean. Primitive values are translated to (or from) sequences of bytes according to the buffer's current byte order, which may be retrieved and modified via the order methods. Specific byte orders are represented by instances of the ByteOrder class. The initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.

and `ByteOrder` provides access to the [native order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#nativeOrder%28%29) for the platform you're working on.

Compare that to the older [`DataInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt%28%29) which is not useful for interop with local native services:

> Reads four input bytes and returns an int value. Let a-d be the first through fourth bytes read. The value returned is:
>
> ```
> (((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) |
>  ((c & 0xff) << 8) | (d & 0xff))
> ```

Answer (score 8):

The Java virtual machine abstracts this consideration away, such that you should not need to worry about it as long as you are working entirely within Java. The only reason you should have to consider byte order is if you are communicating with a non-java process, or something similar.

**Edit:** edited for clarity of wording

Comment: Have to downvote.  There is one other major time to worry about endianness, when you are dealing with a binary file that was written out by a non-Java app with different endiness.  Is endiness a word?  :-)

Comment: @user949300 what you say is true, though I would say that falls under the heading of "communicating with a non-java process"

Comment: I don't know how to "un-downvote", but I'm easy, so I just upvoted it.  However, to me "communicating" implies network stuff, not reading from a file.  Would be clearer if he explicitly mentioned files.  BTW, some file standards define endiness, so even if Java wrote the file the endiness may not be the Java standard.

Comment: is it safe to bitwise-and a primitive `long` with a literal eg. `0xFFFFFFFF00000000L`?

Answer (score 2):

The class file format itself is big-endian (or rather all multiple byte data in the class file is stored in such a way):

[Class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html)

> All 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit quantities are constructed by reading in two, four, and eight consecutive 8-bit bytes, respectively. Multibyte data items are always stored in big-endian order, where the high bytes come first.

But as mentioned by others, as a practical consideration you should almost never have to worry about this.